# Logic Apps Table Storage Get Entities action returns no/unusual results

Tags: odata, azure-logic-apps, azure-table-storage

I have a boolean column in an Azure Table Storage table called `reported`. It looks like this:

[image]

From within an Azure Logic App, I'm trying to use the [Get Entities action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azuretables/#get-entities) to pull all records where `recorded eq null` OR where `recorded ne true`.

I can't seem to find the correct syntax for parsing `null`. The [docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/querying-tables-and-entities#filtering-on-boolean-properties) have no reference to nulls.

**Tried so far:**

- These all return a blank array of results

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

- This returns an error

[image]

```
{
  "odata.error": {
    "code": "InvalidInput",
    "message": {
      "lang": "en-US",
      "value": "One of the request inputs is not valid.\nRequestId:21e33cd2-c002-001d-17eb-8d7c61000000\nTime:2021-08-10T13:27:02.5345973Z"
    }
  }
}
```

- These return the only true record in the table

[image]
[image]

**What am I missing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried reproducing the same and found this
[image]

As it is a boolean value and there is no values assigned to `reported` property in the entity, the value isn't showing up. There has to be either true or false value to the `reported` property to perform manipulations. That's the reason why you cannot find the `reported` column which are null.

In order to make it visible you can make the null to false and so that you can access them having *filter query* to be `reported eq 'false'`

Comment: Aha! Very good to know that Table Storage actions do not bring back `nulls`. Thank you.